# Receiving error status code 400 on Apollo GraphQL query to Node.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, apollo

I'm having trouble with an Apollo to Node.js query with two required arguments. The query works in GraphiQL, however I'm receiving an error with Apollo and React, as shown below. When running the query from React and Apollo, the request doesn't even make it to the resolve function of my GraphQL Node.js api. I know this because I have console.log() statements that aren't running.

The error is this: ApolloError: Response not successful: Received status code 400

Below is the code:

SavingsDashboard.js

```
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import { GET_DATA } from './queries/queries';
import "./App.css";

function Dashboard() {
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_DATA, {
        variables: {
            accountID: 1,
            auth: "test"
        }
    });

    if (loading) return 'Loading...';
    if (error) return `Error: ${error}`;

    console.log(data);
    
    return (
        <div></div>
    )
}
```

queries.js

```
import { gql } from '@apollo/client';

const GET_DATA = gql 
 `query GetData($accountID: String!, $auth: String!) {
    data(accountID: $accountID, auth: $auth) {
            id
            name
        }
    
`

export { GET_DATA };
```

schema.js

```
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: {
        data: {
            type: new GraphQLList(DataType), 
            args: { 
                accountID: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt) },
                auth: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) }
            },
            async resolve(parent, args) {
                console.log(args);
                
                return { }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason the request didn't go through is that I passed an int variable in the useQuery function in Dashboard.js but the query took a string parameter in query.js.

Comment: One should update the question with their solution with EDIT tag and should not add answer or self question

Comment: That's not true @VickyAhuja - self answering a question is legitimate. Editing the question with the answer makes it appear that the question has never been answered. mfusco - you should also accept your own answer.